# Does Nest.ConnectionSettings.SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier even work?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Here is my question. Due to project needs, we have to keep our dates within elasticsearch index in the same format. What we've tried is the next way -

```
            var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(nodeList);
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
                 .SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(
                  m => m.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK")
            // other configuration goes here
```

But it didn't work out. Searching through ES index, I saw dates with dropped trailing zeros ( like 2015-05-05T18:55:27Z insted of expected 2015-05-05T18:55:27.0000000Z). Neither did next option help:

```
            var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(nodeList);
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
                 .SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(m =>
                    {
                        m.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK"});
                    })
            // other configuration goes here
```

With digging into ElasticClient at run-time, I've found that eventually there is a contract resolver which seems like overrides all those settings:

```
          public class ElasticContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
          {
              protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
              {
                  JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
                  ...
                  if (objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?))
                      contract.Converter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
                  ...
                  if (this.ConnectionSettings.ContractConverters.HasAny())
                  {
                      foreach (var c in this.ConnectionSettings.ContractConverters)
                      {
                          var converter = c(objectType);
                          if (converter == null)
                              continue;
                          contract.Converter = converter;
                          break;
                      }
                  }

                 return contract;
             }
          }
```

So if I have it right, without specifying a converter explicitly(**via Connection Settings.AddContractJsonConverters()**), my json settings will be gone since **IsoDateTimeConverter** is instantiated with the default settings rather than ones I've passed through **SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier**.

Has anyone run into this issue? Or I'm just missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handled custom date format for my needs:

```
public class Document
{
    [ElasticProperty(DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd", Type = FieldType.Date)]
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

client.Index(new Document {CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")});
```

My document in ES

```
{
    "_index": "indexname",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "AU04kd4jnBKFIw7rP3gX",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "createdDate": "2015-05-09"
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Rob! It seems to be a way out. Also I've found out that using `ConnectionSettings.AddContractJsonConverters` solves the problem. But it's still confusing why `ConnectionSettings.SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier` doesn't work properly.

Comment: It's worth to report this issue here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

Comment: Agree. Just was curious if it's my fault like I simply forgot something to set up.